# Unable to import kerberos.schema

Tags: linux, rhel, kerberos, openldap

I am trying to import kerberos.schema into OpenLDAP on RHEL7.

I create a file with include /etc/ldap/schema/kerberos.schema in it and then run:

slapcat -f schema_convert.conf -F /tmp/ldif_output -n0 -s "cn={12}kerberos,cn=schema,cn=config" > /tmp/cn=kerberos.ldif

I get

5a1707bf /etc/openldap/schema/kerberos.schema: line 604: unknown directive  outside backend info and database definitions.

and line 604 is

objectclass: ( 2.16.840.1.113719.1.301.6.1.1
                NAME 'krbContainer'
                SUP top
                STRUCTURAL
                MUST ( cn ) )

I'm really not sure where to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was just a simple mistake in the kerberos.schema that I must have done while moving it over. I installed a fresh copy and it's fine.